# How can I divide my data table called (my_data2) in two samples

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to divide my data table called (my_data2) in two samples called (learning sample and test sample). How to apply the logistic regression on the first part of my table (the first sample), then apply predict on the second part? Thank you.
This is my coding;

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit

FNAME2 ="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Nouveau dossier (2)/table.csv"
FinalTableau=np.savetxt(FNAME2,my_data[index_to_use] , delimiter=",")
my_data2 = np.genfromtxt (FNAME2, delimiter = ',')

x= my_data2 [:,1]
a= my_data2[:,3]
#x with values 1 and 2
print x

#converts my binary data series from (1, 2) to (0,1)
x= my_data[:, 1] - 1
print x

form = 'x ~ a'
affair_model = logit (form, my_data2)

affair_result = affair_model.fit ()

print affair_result.summary ()
print affair_result.predict()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split `my_data2` into two arrays of roughly equal size:

```
N = len(my_data2)//2
learning_sample, test_sample = my_data2[:N], my_data2[N:]
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit

FNAME2 = "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Nouveau dossier (2)/table.csv"
FinalTableau = np.savetxt(FNAME2, my_data[index_to_use], delimiter=",")
my_data2 = np.genfromtxt(FNAME2, delimiter=',')

# converts my binary data series from (1, 2) to (0,1)
my_data2[:, 1] -= 1  
# print my_data2

N = len(my_data2)//2
learning_sample, test_sample = my_data2[:N], my_data2[N:]
x = learning_sample[:, 1]
a = learning_sample[:, 3]
# x with values 1 and 2
print x

form = 'x ~ a'
affair_model = logit(form, learning_sample)
affair_result = affair_model.fit()

print affair_result.summary()
print affair_result.predict()
```

Comment: Yes i'm sory, the correct sentence is x = my_data2[:, 1] - 1. It helps to recuperate the second column.

Comment: You could adjust the data first, before splitting it into two parts. I've edited the code above to show what I mean.

Comment: Ok but how can I recuperate the values of the second column of  my_data2[:N]?

Comment: So if i would recuperate the second column of test_sample,also i make x = test_sample[:, 1]?

Comment: When i make this command affair_model = logit(form, learning_sample), i get error!!!